# array allowed not allowed

Tags: arrays, tcl

I have the script "proc backup". I have to each directory many words to allowed or not allowed.
I thought that integrade with a array. but I do not get ahead ...

or is there something simpler?

```
bind pubm - "*fertig*" backup

proc backup {nick host handle channel text} {
    set name[lindex [split [stripcodes bcru $text]] 2]
    set dir[lindex [split [stripcodes bcru $text]] 4]

    if {[catch {exec sh backup.sh $dir $name} error]} {
        putlog $error
    }

    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :backup $name done";
}

array set allowed { 
    "dir1"          "to rar"
    "dir2"          "backupserver1 "
    "dir3"          "2016 2017"
}

array set not_allowed { 
    "dir1"          "test crap"
    "dir2"          "old backupserver2 jpg zip"
    "dir3"          "2015 2014 2013 2012 2011 2010 209 19"
}
```

edit :

line from irc: ( lindex 2 and 4)

run backup.sh only when this word in name is

word0 word1 backupserver1 word3 dir2

not run backup when another word is

word0 word1 backupserver55 word3 dir2

not run backup.sh

word0 word1 test word3 dir1
word0 word1 crap word3 dir1

run backup.sh only when this word in name is

word0 word1 black word3 dir1

Only run when a word from the set allowed in the $name is.
Not run when a word from not_allowed in the $name is.

Comment: Please write some more about what you expect to happen and what not. Right now, I don't understand what the significance of the `allowed` and `not_allowed` arrays really are.

Comment: example: when in dir1 ($dir) the text includes ($name ) "to" or "rar" (from array set allowed) then make if {[catch {exec sh backup.sh ...., and when in dir1 ($dir) the text includes ($name) "test" or "crap"  (from array set not_allowed) then stop (retourn 0), i hope its better so. regards

Answer (score 0):

The following 2 lines are missing a space between the variable name and value.

```
set name[lindex [split [stripcodes bcru $text]] 2]
set dir[lindex [split [stripcodes bcru $text]] 4]
```

Try this:

```
set name [lindex [split [stripcodes bcru $text]] 2]
set dir [lindex [split [stripcodes bcru $text]] 4]
```

Comment: yes thx, its from copy removed .. but that is not the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I have now make this to test, when i have one word then working perfekt,

```
"dir1"          "rar"
```

when have 2 words

```
"dir1"          "rar to"
```

working not.

I would like to respond if the word is "rar" or to word "to" in the text from $relname is

```
bind pubm - "*fertig*" trade

proc backup {nick host handle channel text} {

set name [lindex [split [stripcodes bcru $text]] 2]
set dir [lindex [split [stripcodes bcru $text]] 4]

set rulesall [rulesallow $dir $release]

putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :rulesall $rulesall"
}


array set allowed { 
"dir1"          "rar"

}


proc rulesallow { cat relname} {
global allowed  
foreach {category allowede} [array get allowed] {
    if { [string match -nocase "*$allowede*" "$relname"] } {
    return $allowede;
    } else {

    }
}
}
```

to test have the sh command removed.

Regards